# Difference equation (Discrete time) to Differential Equation (Continuous time)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Suppose I have the following difference equation
\begin{equation}
v(t+2) + a v(t+1) + b v(t) = 0.
\end{equation}
I wish to convert it to a second order ODE. How does one go about doing this? (note: initial conditions are arbitrary).

I have tried using a taylor series where I introduced $v(t+2) \to v(t+2h)$ and so on, but this did not lead anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2\left( {v(t+2) - v(t)\over 2} \right )+ a\left({v(t+1) - v(t) \over 1}\right) + (b + a + 1)v(t) = 0$. Convert this to

$$2\left( {v(t+2h) - v(t)\over 2h} \right )+ a\left({v(t+h) - v(t) \over h}\right) + (b + a + 1)v(t) = 0$$

and let $h \to 0$ to get $(2 + a)\dot v + (b + a + 1)v = 0$.

That is one possible way to convert it to an ODE. There are others. You'll note that it isn't particularly useful unless $ t \gg 1$.

**Edit:** To make this a 2nd order ODE,

If $v'(t) \leftrightarrow v(t+1) - v(t)$, then $$\begin{align}v''(t) &\leftrightarrow v'(t+1) - v'(t) \\&\leftrightarrow (v(t+2) - v(t+1)) - (v(t+1) - v(t)) \\&\leftrightarrow v(t+2) + v(t) - 2v(t+1).\end{align}$$

So we rearrange the original expression to
$$(v(t+2) + v(t) - 2v(t+1)) + (a +2)(v(t+1) - v(t)) + (b + a + 1)v(t)$$
and convert to
$$v'' + (a+2)v' +(b + a + 1)v = 0.$$

Comment: this is not second order though.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that requirement.

Comment: Please see the edit.